# Opening a custom dialog inside of an alert dialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask, dialog, android-alertdialog

Ok,this is going to get a bit complicated, but hang with me. I have the following scenario that I cannot get to work:

1. Prompt the user to save (ok or cancel)
2. In onclick for "ok", do a Async task to get some data. Do this synchronously
3. Then create a custom dialog to display that data to prompt the user for more info [THIS PART DOES NOT WORK)
4. The do another Async task where I save the data.

So, is there an inherent problem with creating a custom Dialog inside of a AlertDialog?

The behavior that happens is that all operations run, and at the end the custom Dialog briefly appears and then disappears. It should show up before the last Async task and not let the Async task execute before it has gathered the data needed.

I have simplified the problem code to this:

```
                    AlertDialog.Builder submitDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                submitDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to end this Preview of the form? It will no longer be availabe for editing");
                }
                else {
                    submitDialog.setTitle("Submit?");
                    submitDialog.setMessage("Are you sure?");
                }
                submitDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
                submitDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {

                             // =============================
                             // 1st Async
                             // =============================
                             // Make synchronous since need data. Must be a task cause hitting server
                             Test test = null;
                             try {
                                 test = new workflowTask().execute().get();
                             }
                             catch (Exception ex) {
                                 // nothing
                             }


                             // =============================
                             // Customer Dialog Get more info
                             // =============================
                             // Prompt for data here...
                             String[] listContent = {"test1@test.com", "test2@test.com"};
                            // custom dialog
                            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MyActivity.this);
                            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_email_picker);
                            dialog.setTitle("Select email and enter comments");
                            ListView emails = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.emaillist);

                            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (MyActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContent);
                            emails.setAdapter(adapter);
                            emails.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            });

                            Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);

                            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ok clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                            });
                            dialog.show();


                             // =============================
                             // 2nd Async
                             // =============================
                             new submitFormResultTask().execute();
                         }
                     }
                 });
                submitDialog.show();
```

Comment: Why not just dismiss the alert dialog on the postExecute of the first asynctask after getting the data? Then display your custom dialog with the retrieved data when you ask for more info. That way you avoid the problem altogether.

Comment: Sort of echoing @DigitalNinja, I think you should change your UI. Multiple dialogs at the same time or in quick succession is not a good user experience. Use an Activity or a _single_ custom dialog that handles the entire flow (and presumably stays on screen for the whole duration). You can have the input field(s) become disabled when the user submits and show a spinner while the first AsyncTask is working.

Comment: @DigitalNinja. I tried that - dismissing the original alert dialog in the postExecute without success. Not sure if I am doing something wrong there.

Comment: @StephenMcCormick I have done something similar with dialogs and tasks. I'm not sure how to provide any help without seeing it. Are you still having trouble with this?

Comment: @DigitalNinja I think I have it solved. I believe the problem was doing the the following : AlertDialog -> AsyncTask -> Dialog -> AsyncTask. I moved the last AsyncTask into the onClick of the Dialog and it is all happy. Though perhaps you or someone else can explain why that works.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use a viewflipper in your "unique" custom dialog? so after first click on OK you can check if first page is visible and then you can show second page and only from this moment if user press on OK you can recall the dismiss() method.

In this way, you can perform a sort of wizard with possibility to return on first view if user needs to change something. Make sense?

Comment: The steps are slightly more involved. This scenario occurs only on a special condition - so it is not always encountered. I guess I could create an original dialog with a hidden section upon selection of "Ok", but then in essence it is a different dialog, since I will not want to display what I have just displayed. Not sure pushing it to an activity will change anything since there will still be the step of an original async, then a dialog followed by another async.

Comment: Also this can happen in 3 different places in the code, with the added complexity of it being in a loop. Thought I would first try the simple scenario. That said I will attempt each of these suggestions and see what works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference the way I solved this was to actually call the AsyncTask in the onClick of the 2nd Dialog. Kind of ugly, but I could not get anything else to work. I would have thought that so long as it was a modal dialog being run that Android would pause till its work was accomplished - it did not, it just ran the next line of code (2nd AsyncTask). So it looks something like:

AlertDialog ->
    AsyncTask.get() (so synchronous)
    Customer Dialog
         onClick->
         2nd AsyncTask